# Trying to understand why none of my tensorflow-gpu import statements are working

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I'm using anaconda to run through a google code lab with tensorflow on my Windowsx64 machine. Followed directions and got the model trained nicely, all was good. Then I decided to try again with tensorflow-gpu.

So I uninstalled tensorflow, and installed tensorflow-gpu using anaconda. (conda uninstall tensorflow -> conda install tensorflow-gpu). Supposedly, anaconda is supposed to take care of cuDNN versions and so forth. In my terminal, I can run python and in the interpreter run:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> print(tf.__version__)
1.8.0
```

Looking great so far.
I try

```
>>> sess = tf.Session()
```

and get a nice long output with my GeForce GTX 1050 driver listed as it should be, with compute capability 6.1, well above the 3.5 threshold.

Awesome.

But then when I try to go back and run my code, every other statement I use with tf fails.
For example, from [Tensorflow's GPU documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu), they recommend running the following code to check that the GPU is working:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
```

and my result is:

```
>>> print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'config'
```

Further down they recommend enabling debugging with:

```
tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)
```

My result:

```
>>> tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'debugging'
```

Needless to say, when I go back to my original code from my codelab, it fails on the first line that uses tf aside from the original import statement itself. Am I missing something basic here? Why are none of my tf commands recognized?

Any ideas what's up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably your tensorflow version is too old. I'm on 2.1 and that line works for me so I'm guessing they introduced config in 2.0 or something. Anyways, try the one that they deprecated instead. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/test/is_gpu_available

Comment: Interesting that the deprecated command works. According to Anaconda I have the latest install of tensorflow-gpu, though. However, checking out the documentation it looks like they are on later versions now - I guess Anaconda is outdated? That is...disappointing. Thanks for helping me pinpoint the issue!

Comment: @EmmanuelGallegos Can you share the contents of the environment? You should be able to get tensorflow-gpu v2.1.0 on windows (https://anaconda.org/anaconda/tensorflow-gpu).